# How to apply restriction on a column value based on another column value in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have come across a requirement where I need to apply restriction on column C based on values in column A

Suppose,

Column A value = "DSOC" , Then I don't want any value in column C.So if user tries to make an entry in Column C it should throw an error showing that Column C entry not allowed for "DSOC"

Column C entry should be done only if Column A value is = "DSOF".

Answer (score 0):

You can use Excel's Data Validation feature to achieve this. Select the entire column and then implement following formula.

`=ISNA(VLOOKUP(B1,A:A,1,0))`

Refer below snapshot.

[image: Data Validation]

Comment: This is going to search the entire A column for the value.But what I need is lets say if A6 is "DSOC" then there should be a restriction for C6 and no value should be allowed to fill.If A7 is "DSOF" then column C6 should be allowed to fill the value.

Comment: @AshutoshRai This is not clear in your question. You should've included this in your question to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to complete the requirement in the following way.I just found the address of the cell which I tried to edit by using the below formula in the screensot[image]

If the value is DSOF then I am displaying an error message